# Why am I getting this error? How to handle Null Values. Message=Must specify additional parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-foxpro

So I'm writing a data export, between SQL and Foxpro, I'm using parameterised strings in order to pull through the necessary data, I am also using string concatenation to get the information requested on certain records, this seemed to be working fine until I reached the sort code record, wherein the stated error became prevalent.

As a quick rundown. Establishing the connection to both databases.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var exportConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString: "Data Source=Localhost;"
                                                                          + "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                                                                          + @"connection timeout=30;"
                                                                          + @"database=001-CARL_V4"))
        using (var importConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString: @"Provider=vfpoledb.1;"
                                                                            +
                                                                            @"data source=C:\Users\Joshua.cameron\Desktop\PCHomesImportTestBlank\PCHomesServer\DATABASE\pchomes.dbc")
            )
```

I'm setting up the command to select from SQL:

```
            using (SqlCommand exportCommand = new SqlCommand(@"select 
    [ID]
    ,[OwTitle]
    ,[OwForenames]
    ,[OwSurname]      
    ,[OwNum]
    ,[OwAddress1]
    ,[OwAddress2]
    ,[OwAddress3]
    ,[OwAddress4]
    ,[OwPostcode]
    ,[OwPhHome]
    ,[OwPhWork]
    ,[OwPhFax]
    ,[OwPhMobile]
    ,[OwEMail]
    ,[OwBankName]
    ,[OwAccNo]
    ,[OwAccName]
    ,[OwSalutation]
    ,[OwNotes]
    ,[OwSort1]
    ,[OwSort2]
    ,[OwSort3]
```

from dbo.CARL_Owners", exportConnection))

And the command to insert into VFP:

```
using (OleDbCommand importCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO CLIENT 
    (CLCODE
    ,clcodedesc
    ,Title
    ,Fname
    ,Sname
    ,Address1
    ,Address3
    ,Address5
    ,Address4
    ,Address6
    ,Postcode
    ,Phoneh
    ,PhoneW
    ,Facsimileh
    ,Mobile
    ,Emailaddr
    ,Bankname
    ,Bankacno
    ,Bankacna
    ,Salute
    ,Notes
    ,BANKSORT
    ) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
            importConnection))
```

Adding in the parameterised values to the above INSERT statement:

```
importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("clcode", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("clcodedesc", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fname", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sname", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address1", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address3", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address5", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address4", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address6", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Postcode", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phoneh", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PhoneW", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Facsimileh", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Mobile", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Emailaddr", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Bankname", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Bankacno", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Bankacna", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Salute", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Notes", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Banksort", "");
```

Open the database connections:

```
exportConnection.Open();
            importConnection.Open();
```

Populate the above strings with values pulled from SQL:

```
var exportReader = exportCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (exportReader.Read())
            {
                string part1 = exportReader.GetSqlValue(2).ToString();
                string part2 = exportReader.GetSqlValue(3).ToString();
                string space = " ";
                string code = exportReader.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();
                string clcode = exportReader.GetSqlValue(2).ToString();
                string title = exportReader.GetSqlValue(1).ToString();
                string sort1 = exportReader.GetSqlValue(20).ToString();
                string sort2 = exportReader.GetSqlValue(21).ToString();
                string sort3 = exportReader.GetSqlValue(22).ToString();
                // ID
                importCommand.Parameters["clcode"].Value = string.Concat(clcode,code);
                //
                importCommand.Parameters["clcodedesc"].Value = string.Concat(title,space,part1,space,part2);
                //OwTitle
                importCommand.Parameters["Title"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(1).ToString();
                //OwForenames
                importCommand.Parameters["Fname"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(2).ToString();
                //OwSurname
                importCommand.Parameters["Sname"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(3).ToString();
                //OwNum
                importCommand.Parameters["Address1"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(4).ToString();
                //[OwAddress1]
                //[OwAddress2]
                //[OwAddress3]
                //[OwAddress4]
                importCommand.Parameters["Address3"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(5).ToString();
                importCommand.Parameters["Address5"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(6).ToString();
                importCommand.Parameters["Address4"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(7).ToString();
                importCommand.Parameters["Address6"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(8).ToString();
                //OwPostcode
                importCommand.Parameters["Postcode"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(9).ToString();
                //OwPhHome
                importCommand.Parameters["Phoneh"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(10).ToString();
                //OwPhWork
                importCommand.Parameters["PhoneW"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(11).ToString();
                //OwPhFax
                importCommand.Parameters["Facsimileh"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(12).ToString();
                //OwPhMobile
                importCommand.Parameters["Mobile"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(13).ToString();
                //OwEMail
                importCommand.Parameters["Emailaddr"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(14).ToString();
                //OwBankName
                importCommand.Parameters["Bankname"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(15).ToString();
                //OwAccNo
                importCommand.Parameters["Bankacno"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(16).ToString();
                //OwAccName
                importCommand.Parameters["Bankacna"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(17).ToString();
                //OwSalutation
                importCommand.Parameters["Salute"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(18).ToString();
                //OwNotes
                importCommand.Parameters["Notes"].Value = exportReader.GetSqlValue(19).ToString();
                //OwSort1
                //OwSort2
                //OwSort3
                importCommand.Parameters["Banksort"].Value = string.Concat(sort1, sort2, sort3);
```

The commented lines are the associated records in the SQL database.

Finally I execute the query and close the connections:

```
  try
                {
                    importCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Write("Error Writing to database");
                    Console.Write(e);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }

            // done
            Console.WriteLine("Complete!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            exportConnection.Close();
            importConnection.Close();
```

My theory is that this string value:

```
                    importCommand.Parameters["Banksort"].Value = string.Concat(sort1, sort2, sort3);
```

is causing issues, as the first records in the table are "NULL"

Comment: You really should not be using `AddWithValue` like that, just use `Add(` and use the overload that takes in a `DbType`.

Comment: oh right? Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: Well, `AddWithValue(`  takes a best guess at what the datatype of the parameter should be based on what you passed in to the value, `Add(` you can tell it exactly what the data type should be so there is no chance for error from a incorrect best guess.

Comment: You surely should be using AddWithValue. Error has nothing to do with that.

Comment: You need to set parameter values to `DBNull.Value` if the underlying value is null.  A parameter with a value of `null` will not be included in the SQL statement.

Comment: Why wouldn't you take the easier path, and do the insert into ... from within VFP code using ExecScript as I showed you in your older thread? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely should be using AddWithValue. Error has nothing to do with that. You should follow the message to find out the reason of the error :) It is saying "Must specify additional parameters". It means that you have less parameters than what you really should supply. IOW the error is in the count of ? placeholders. They are treated positionally and must match the count of the expected value count. ie:

```
insert into myTable (field1, field2) values (?,?)
```

is correct, while:

```
insert into myTable (field1, field2) values (?)
```

would give the error you see. You say, you have 2 columns but specify only 1 parameter placeholder. Add enough ? (as I can see 22 values and 21 ? exists there). And of course do not forget to add the parameters (with AddWithValue) in the same order of those expected parameters (first AddWithValue() binds to first ? and thus field1, second binds to second ? and thuse field2 and so on).

PS: You could write that SQL like this so you wouldn't count the ? wrong:

```
string fields = @"CLCODE
  ,clcodedesc
  ,Title
  ,Fname
  ,Sname
  ,Address1
  ,Address3
  ,Address5
  ,Address4
  ,Address6
  ,Postcode
  ,Phoneh
  ,PhoneW
  ,Facsimileh
  ,Mobile
  ,Emailaddr
  ,Bankname
  ,Bankacno
  ,Bankacna
  ,Salute
  ,Notes
  ,BANKSORT";

string sql = string.Format( "INSERT INTO CLIENT ({0}) values ({1})", 
  fields, 
  string.Join(",",fields.Split(',').Select(f => "?")));
```

Comment: very nice way to avoid `?` count mismatch. +1

Comment: You sir are a hero, thank you very much, that was the exact issue.
I can't believe I missed that.